# Using node.js and express to process a POST request

Tags: javascript, http, node.js, post, express

I am new to learning AJAX and new to web development at all, and I am having trouble having my local server and my remote server process a post request. I am using node.js and the express module.

Here is the code of my server:

```
var express = require('express');

//start server
var app = express.createServer();

//handle requests
app.post('/hello', function(req, res){
    res.send("hello");
});

app.listen(8888);
```

Pretty basic, I know. To test this, I create an XMLHttpRequest manually through the console in Chrome (I have disabled the Cross-Origin policy to test on my local machine):

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('POST', 'localhost:8888/hello', true);
xhr.send('name=me'); //body of request is irrelevant at this point
```

When I send the request to my local machine, it returns immediately and says it failed. When I send the request to my remote server (where **localhost** is replaced by my server's IP) I don't get the error in my console, but when I check the xhr object's status is failed.

I don't know whether the problem is with the way my server is written, or the way I am sending the request to the server. However, I have been looking at tutorials and examples that show express processing post requests like I do above, and other tutorials that show sending POST requests like I do above.

Sending and processing GET requests seems to work fine. I must be missing something.

Thanks, Xaan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to include HTTP in your URL when you issue the POST:

```
xhr.open('POST', 'http://localhost:8888/hello', true);
```

Comment: Thank you, this was the problem! Any idea why? It works for GET requests without the 'http://'...

Comment: @Xaan The `host` of a URL needs to be prefixed by at least `//` -- `//localhost:3000/hello`. Without that, it'll be treated as a relative URL to the current address -- keeping the `file://` it sounds like you're using for the page.

Answer (score 1):

XHR does not work if the calling js is not served by a webserver.

What you should do is add a simple route on your Express server

```
app.get('/', function( req, res) {
  res.sendfile('index.html');
})
```

Where index.html contains your testing code.

If you want to test from a different webserver and be confronted with the annoying Cross-Origin policy you can also use this super usefull command to spawn a webserver in your current folder:

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer
```

I use it so often that I actually alias it:

```
alias www='python -m SimpleHTTPServer'
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am trying to test your solution. I have my local machine run a node server that redirects to the index.html file where I have my testing code to test the server on my remote machine. However, the xhr's object status is [Exception: DOMException]. Shouldn't this work? Thanks again.

Comment: And by the way you should jQuery to make xhr calls. It offer good wrapping and x-platform.